# how to optimize this query to load friends fast

Tags: php, mysql

This is my attached code there i have defined query.

```
SELECT
  is_facebook_user,
  fname,
  lname,
  profilenam,
  mem_id,
  gender,
  profile_type,
  photo_thumb,
  photo_b_thumb
FROM members
WHERE mem_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT
          mem_id            AS frnd
        FROM network
        WHERE mem_id = '$userId'
             OR frd_id = '$userId')
ORDER BY profilenam;
```

here i wanted to fetch the friends asap.I have also applied indexes on mem_id and frd_id.But still 2500 friends take long time and response of function prints very slowly.

Thanks 
sparks
[find code link here](http://codepad.org/NPEQz6ph)

Comment: Show us your table structure along with indexes.

Comment: You should check the time that your query takes to execute. (for example, paste it into phpmyadmin, and check the time). For me it is more likely that the foreach after the query, or the display is taking longer. You can have a rough idea by ending your script (with `die();`) just after the query, just after the foreach, just after the display and see what really takes time.

Comment: Are you sure it's the query that takes long or maybe the function itself? Have you tried running just the query against the DB and see the result?

Comment: @pinouchon yes its while loop that is taking time of abt 32 sec. ow can decrease it....plz

Answer (score 1):

How about a join?

```
SELECT
  m.is_facebook_user,
  m.fname,
  m.lname,
  m.profilenam,
  m.mem_id,
  m.gender,
  m.profile_type,
  m.photo_thumb,
  m.photo_b_thumb
FROM members m
  join network n
    on m.mem_id = n.mem_id
WHERE n.mem_id = '$userId'
     or n.frd_id = '$userId'
ORDER BY m.profilenam;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join like this

```
SELECT
  is_facebook_user,
  fname,
  lname,
  profilenam,
  mem_id,
  gender,
  profile_type,
  photo_thumb,
  photo_b_thumb
FROM members
  left join (select
           distince   mem_id
         from network
         where mem_id = '$userId'
          OR frd_id = '$userId') as e
    on e.mem_id = members.mem_id
```